# joomla custom component memory usage

Tags: php, memory, joomla, components, joomla-extensions

I have written a custom component for my Joomla Website.
The component is in php and is based on MVC paradigm. The component works but after several months of use, in some parts it appears this message:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XXXXX bytes exhausted (tried to allocate XXX bytes) in XXX\my_sql.php
```

My component does different queries on database. The website has 256M like memory limit. I know that I can increase the memory to 512MB, but there are other methods? How can I understand how much memory does my component use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following will show debug information to all users; so you might want to do this offline on your development machine, (make a copy of the production database).

Enable debug in the configuration, then open Extensions-Plugins and enable the Debug plugin; now reload the frontend, you will see the time, memory, and the complete list of queries (you should see something like the screenshot attached below, clicking on the titles opens them. If you don't see it, temporarily set one of the default templates for your site (and let the template designer know he forgot to include the debug placeholder).

The amount of memory you exhausted is php's so most likely you are keeping too much stuff in memory. If you are iterating through a result set, making new queries, and caching the results in an object, this may be the reason, and you can solve it quickly by iterating fewer records at a time on the main query (a dirty solution indeed, but no other changes are usually needed)

**A quick way to isolate the part that's causing problems**

You can start logging your memory with `memory_get_usage()`  and shortly you should be able to point out the (hopefully single) point where it grows out of control.  Then apply the above suggestions to fix it.

[image: joomla debug info]

Comment: This extension is already active but I don't see the time,memory etc...

Comment: ensure you enable debug in the site global configuration too: you should see something like the image I'm attaching to the main post

Comment: Ok, now I have the debug. Looking all the information that the debug returns I don't see any strange things. It seems also that I don't use much memory. Any idea to optimize the code?

Comment: Yes, the error is obviously on line 386. jk how can we know? both I and lucacatr suggested some options, and now it is up to you to figure out how you are wasting memory.  If you can't figure it out, yet, I just added another suggestion to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are processing a lot of data. Enable the debug console as indicated by Riccardo to test your queries. Check also if you are using array_push or similar functions casting a big amount of data. You can also use Xdebug to see where the bottleneck of the code is. You can find a guide to set it up here [Xdebug](https://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_Xdebug_for_PHP_development)

Comment: Yes, I also use array_push. Is there an alternative for array_push?

Comment: If you want to add multiple values into the array with only then use array_push, or else use $array[] = that is faster to add only one value.